# Viewing Different Tabs from a TabHost in IntelliJ IDEA's UI Designer

Tags: android, intellij-idea

Is there a way to switch the tab you are viewing from a TabHost in the IntelliJ IDEA Android UI Designer?

Here is me selecting Tab1:
[image: Successfully viewing tab 1]

As you can see the tab is encompassed by a blue frame.

Here is me attempting to select Tab 2:
[image: Failing to select tab 2]

As you can see, that big big dark-blue square on the left is supposed to be the TAB but everything I put in it will not show up. I cannot find an option to view it. .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of March 5th 2014 it is **impossible** to switch which tab you are viewing from a TabHost in the UI Designer. The bug was reported [November 30th of 2012](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-96301#tab=Comments) and has yet to be touched.

Answer (score 0):

If everything you need is just rearrangement of controls on inactive tab, you could temporarily make the tab first, because UI Designer always shows content of the first tab only

Answer (score 0):

By mouse, select the `FrameLayout` then long left click on any space in it.